# when concatenating video segments ffmpeg shows error: "Media type mismatch between the parsed_overlay_20"

Tags: types, ffmpeg, concatenation, mismatch

773/5000
I'm trying to apply a scaling and chromakey effect to different segments of a video and then combine those segments again into one.

To improve the time and performance I have developed a program that creates all the filters in a single command.

The plan is simple, I have a video * .mov recorded with a green screen and a background * .jpg,

1. I first prepare a couple of backgrounds with blur effect from the JPG image
2. I then apply chromakey to make the green part of the video transparent
3. I trim the video to which I applied the chromakey in several time segments and to each segment I applied a scale and crop and I overlay it to one of the backgrounds prepared in step 1
4. Concatenate all segments already processed.

When I execute the resulting command it gives me the error

the command is this:

```
ffmpeg -i "C:\ffmpeg\pruebas\FFBlue_ProjectsFiles\chroma\green1.mov" -i C:\ffmpeg\pruebas\FFBlue_ProjectsFiles\fondos\sc.jpg -filter_complex " [1:v]scale=iw*3:-1,crop=w=iw/3:h=ih/3:y=(ih-oh)/3:x=((iw-ow)/2)+(ow/2-ow/3),boxblur=7:2[fondo_3IZQ] ; [1:v]scale=iw*4:-1,crop=w=iw/4:h=ih/4:y=(ih-oh)/3:x=(in_w-out_w)/2,boxblur=6:2[fondo_4CEN] ; [1:v]scale=iw*5:-1,crop=w=iw/5:h=ih/5:y=(ih-oh)/3:x=((iw-ow)/2)+(ow/2-ow/3),boxblur=5:2[fondo_5IZQ]  ; [0]chromakey=color=#83BD46:similarity = 0.1 : blend = 0.05,selectivecolor=reds=0 0 0 -1:yellows=0 0.1 0 -0.5:greens=0 0 -1 0:whites=0 0 0 -0.7 [vid]  ;  [vid] trim=start=0:duration=0,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=iw*4:-1,crop=w=iw/4:h=ih/4:y=(ih-oh)/3:x=((iw-ow)/2)+(ow/2-ow/3)[vid_0] ; [fondo_4CEN][vid_0]overlay[toma_0] ; [vid] trim=start=0:duration=3.41933,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=iw*3:-1,crop=w=iw/3:h=ih/3:y=(ih-oh)/3:x=(in_w-out_w)/2[vid_1] ; [fondo_3IZQ][vid_1]overlay[toma_1] ; [vid] trim=start=3.41932988166809:duration=2.85067,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=iw*5:-1,crop=w=iw/5:h=ih/5:y=(ih-oh)/3:x=(in_w-out_w)/2[vid_2] ; [fondo_5IZQ][vid_2]overlay[toma_2]  ; [toma_0] [toma_1] [toma_2] concat=n=3:v=1:a=1:unsafe=1 [v_concatenado][a_concatenado]" -map [v_concatenado]  -map [a_concatenado] "C:\ffmpeg\pruebas\FFBlue_ProjectsFiles\chroma\green1_FINAL.mov"
```

when I execute it ffmpeg says:

```
[Parsed_overlay_20 @ 0000000000404100] Media type mismatch between the 'Parsed_o
verlay_20' filter output pad 0 (video) and the 'Parsed_concat_26' filter input p
ad 1 (audio)
[AVFilterGraph @ 0000000003527a00] Cannot create the link overlay:0 -> concat:1
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument
```

Comment: I'd like to keep the audio of each section

I suposed that using trim to make video segments will silice audio also

But aparently I do not know how to tell ffmpeg that it should use the audio in the video

please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are telling the concat filter to output an audio stream but you did not provide any audio inputs.

#### 1. Add atrim filters:

```
[0:a]trim=start=1:duration=3,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a0];[1:a]trim=start=10:duration=2,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a1];[2:a]trim=start=100:duration=6,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a2];
```

Adjust the `start` and `duration` values to your needs.

#### 2. Then reference them in the concat filter:

```
[toma_0][a0][toma_1][a1][toma_2][a2]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1:unsafe=1 [v_concatenado][a_concatenado]
```

Comment: I tryed to follow your instructions and this was the resultant command:

Comment: [0:a]trim=start=0:duration=3.41933,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a1];[0:a]trim=3.41932988166809:duration=2.85067,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a2]
...

toma_1][a1][toma_2][a2] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1:unsafe=1 [v_concatenado][a_concatenado]

Comment: @user2642511 Show your full command. You can edit your question to show the new command.